# mechanize,bs4,urllib,urlib2 can not open nseindia.com

Tags: python, urllib2, mechanize, mechanize-python

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
url = 'http://nseindia.com'
br.oprn(url)
```

and error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in
open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 255, in
_mech_open
    raise response
httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt
```

i am try all think like....

```
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.
1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

br.set_handle_equiv(False)


br.set_handle_equiv(False)
```

Comment: Has the answer helped to solve the problem? If yes, consider accepting the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an `Accept` header:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()

br.addheaders = [
    ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36'),
    ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8')
]

url = 'http://nseindia.com'
br.open(url)
```

---

Then, just to prove it is working, parse the response with [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and get the page title:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response())
print soup.title.text
```

Prints:

```
NSE - National Stock Exchange of India Ltd.
```